# is it possible to iterate through each image src in a array and display it on your webpage.?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, setattribute

I am trying to iterate through each individual image source defined in the array. Create a new image element which will set the attribute src of image 1, image 2, etc. until there are no more new image sources to loop through in the array and display it to a webpage.

```js
const u = document.querySelector(".divs:nth-child(3)");
const a = [
  {
    name: "BBQ Becky",
    img: "https://assets.codepen.io/1179484/bbqbecky_1.jpg"
  },
  {
    name: "Permit Patty",
    img: "https://assets.codepen.io/1179484/permitpatty_1.jpg"
  },
  {
    name: "Pool Patrol Puala",
    img: "https://assets.codepen.io/1179484/poolpatrolpaula_1.jpg"
  },
  {
    name: "Wake Up Suzie",
    img: "https://assets.codepen.io/1179484/wakeupsuzie_1.jpg"
  },
  {
    name: "ID Adam",
    img: "https://assets.codepen.io/1179484/idadam_1.jpg"
  }
];

for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  var image = document.createElement("img");
  image.setAttribute("src", a[i].img);
  u.appendChild(image);
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#s1 {
  height: 100vh;
  widht: 100vw;
  background: salmon;
}

img {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<section id="s1">
  <div class="divs"></div>
  <div class="divs"></div>
  <div class="divs"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: image.setAttribute("src", a[i].img); without the quotes around a[i].img

Comment: Also, it would be better to use forEach instead of for, because, if the object (a) is not set correctly or is null, the you will get an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to unquote the `a[i].img` part like this:

```js
const u = document.querySelector(".divs:nth-child(3)");
const a = [
  {
    name: "BBQ Becky",
    img: "https://assets.codepen.io/1179484/bbqbecky_1.jpg"
  },
  {
    name: "Permit Patty",
    img: "https://assets.codepen.io/1179484/permitpatty_1.jpg"
  },
  {
    name: "Pool Patrol Puala",
    img: "https://assets.codepen.io/1179484/poolpatrolpaula_1.jpg"
  },
  {
    name: "Wake Up Suzie",
    img: "https://assets.codepen.io/1179484/wakeupsuzie_1.jpg"
  },
  {
    name: "ID Adam",
    img: "https://assets.codepen.io/1179484/idadam_1.jpg"
  }
];

for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  var image = document.createElement("img");
  image.setAttribute("src", a[i].img);
  u.appendChild(image);
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#s1 {
  height: 100vh;
  widht: 100vw;
  background: salmon;
}

img {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<section id="s1">
  <div class="divs"></div>
  <div class="divs"></div>
  <div class="divs"></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```js
const a = [
  {
    name: "BBQ Becky",
    img: "https://assets.codepen.io/1179484/bbqbecky_1.jpg",
  },
  {
    name: "Permit Patty",
    img: "https://assets.codepen.io/1179484/permitpatty_1.jpg",
  },
  {
    name: "Pool Patrol Puala",
    img: "https://assets.codepen.io/1179484/poolpatrolpaula_1.jpg",
  },
  {
    name: "Wake Up Suzie",
    img: "https://assets.codepen.io/1179484/wakeupsuzie_1.jpg",
  },
  {
    name: "ID Adam",
    img: "https://assets.codepen.io/1179484/idadam_1.jpg",
  },
];

const renderImages = (arr) => {
  for (let i in arr) {
    let image = document.createElement("img");
    image.setAttribute("src", arr[i].img);
    document.body.appendChild(image);
  }
};

renderImages(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using forEach

```js
const u = document.querySelector(".divs:nth-child(3)");
const a = [
  {
    name: "BBQ Becky",
    img: "https://assets.codepen.io/1179484/bbqbecky_1.jpg"
  },
  {
    name: "Permit Patty",
    img: "https://assets.codepen.io/1179484/permitpatty_1.jpg"
  },
  {
    name: "Pool Patrol Puala",
    img: "https://assets.codepen.io/1179484/poolpatrolpaula_1.jpg"
  },
  {
    name: "Wake Up Suzie",
    img: "https://assets.codepen.io/1179484/wakeupsuzie_1.jpg"
  },
  {
    name: "ID Adam",
    img: "https://assets.codepen.io/1179484/idadam_1.jpg"
  }
];

a.forEach(o => {
let image = document.createElement("img");
  image.setAttribute("src", o.img);
  u.appendChild(image);
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#s1 {
  height: 100vh;
  widht: 100vw;
  background: salmon;
}

img {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<section id="s1">
  <div class="divs"></div>
  <div class="divs"></div>
  <div class="divs"></div>
</section>
```